# Cannot find variable "search" in location Class GUI

Tags: user-interface, actionlistener

I don't understand why my variable cannot be recognized as it's in the class above. If you look at the actionPerformed class, you'll see that I've got an if statement for the search button. However, for some reason this does not work as its giving me a variable not found error, even though the variable is in the GUI class.

```
package crimedata;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;


class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Connection con = null;

GUI() {

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Crime Data");

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(600, 600);

    f.setResizable(true);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

    JLabel LongLabel = new JLabel("Enter Longitude here");
    LongLabel.setForeground(Color.gray);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    getContentPane().add(LongLabel, gbc);
    JTextField LongText = new JTextField(20);
    getContentPane().add(LongText, gbc);

    JLabel LatLabel = new JLabel("Enter Latitude here");
    LatLabel.setForeground(Color.gray);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    getContentPane().add(LatLabel, gbc);
    JTextField LatText = new JTextField(20);
    getContentPane().add(LatText, gbc);

    JLabel LSOANameLabel = new JLabel("Enter LSOA Name here");
    LSOANameLabel.setForeground(Color.gray);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    getContentPane().add(LSOANameLabel, gbc);
    JTextField LSOANameText = new JTextField(20);
    getContentPane().add(LSOANameText, gbc);

    JButton search = new JButton("Search");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = -1;
    getContentPane().add(search, gbc);
    search.addActionListener(this);

    JButton exportnoid = new JButton("Export No Crime ID");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = -1;
    getContentPane().add(exportnoid, gbc);

    JButton exportdup = new JButton("Export Duplicate ID");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = -1;
    getContentPane().add(exportdup, gbc);

    f.add(getContentPane());
    pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==search){
        System.out.println("");
    } else {

    }
}

}

class GUIHandler {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI a = new GUI();
}
}
```

Comment: any help? I can't seem to understand what's going wrong here

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you want to have class GUI extends JFrame implements **ActionListener** in order to have "search" (JButton) variable visible to your actionlistener, "search" variable should be a field, not a local variable.

However, after that, if you want to get the text of your 3 textfields inside your action listener and do something with them (like searching) they will have to be fields aswell.

I recommend you to take this approach without implementing ActionListener to your class.

Also, take a look to the main method.

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

class GUI extends JFrame {

    /**
         * 
         */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8880442699222184662L;
    Connection con = null;

    GUI() {

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Crime Data");

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 600);

        f.setResizable(true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        JLabel LongLabel = new JLabel("Enter Longitude here");
        LongLabel.setForeground(Color.gray);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        getContentPane().add(LongLabel, gbc);
        JTextField LongText = new JTextField(20);
        getContentPane().add(LongText, gbc);

        JLabel LatLabel = new JLabel("Enter Latitude here");
        LatLabel.setForeground(Color.gray);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        getContentPane().add(LatLabel, gbc);
        JTextField LatText = new JTextField(20);
        getContentPane().add(LatText, gbc);

        JLabel LSOANameLabel = new JLabel("Enter LSOA Name here");
        LSOANameLabel.setForeground(Color.gray);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        getContentPane().add(LSOANameLabel, gbc);
        JTextField LSOANameText = new JTextField(20);
        getContentPane().add(LSOANameText, gbc);

        JButton search = new JButton("Search");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = -1;
        getContentPane().add(search, gbc);
        search.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("searching....");
            System.out.println("text1:" + LongText.getText());
            System.out.println("text2:" + LatText.getText());
            System.out.println("text3:" + LSOANameText.getText());
        });

        JButton exportnoid = new JButton("Export No Crime ID");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = -1;
        getContentPane().add(exportnoid, gbc);

        JButton exportdup = new JButton("Export Duplicate ID");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = -1;
        getContentPane().add(exportdup, gbc);

        f.add(getContentPane());
        pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class GUIHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // All swing applications must run on their own thread.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GUI a = new GUI();
        });

    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to have all your variables as fields.